# How to grant rights on select from SYS objects to ADMIN user (autonomous cloud database free-tier)

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I can't grant select on some tables (say SYS.AQ$SCHEDULER_EVENT_QTAB).
However, I can see these tables in dba_objects.
I've an absolutely free autonomous database on Oracle cloud.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The ADMIN user does not have privileges to grant access to SYS objects in an Autonomous Database. Because of the shared nature of autonomous database services, full access to the SYS schema is not possible. If access to the tables or views in question cannot be obtained from an existing pre-defined role, then you will not be able to access them directly. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/atpdg/experienced-database-users.html#GUID-798FB413-6160-4EEC-93D1-6D2B996046CE):

> Because Oracle Autonomous Database imposes security controls and
> performs administrative database tasks for you, the ADMIN user does
> not have as many privileges as the SYS user. Here is a list of the
> privileges that the ADMIN user does not have but that the SYS user in
> an Oracle Database does have:
>
> - ALTER LOCKDOWN PROFILE
> - BACKUP ANY TABLE
> - BECOME USER
> - CREATE ANY JOB
> - CREATE ANY LIBRARY
> - CREATE LIBRARY
> - CREATE LOCKDOWN PROFILE
> - CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE
> - DEQUEUE ANY QUEUE
> - DROP LOCKDOWN PROFILE
> - EM EXPRESS CONNECT
> - ENQUEUE ANY QUEUE
> - EXPORT FULL DATABASE
> - FLASHBACK ANY TABLE
> - FLASHBACK ARCHIVE ADMINISTER
> - GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE
> - GRANT ANY ROLE
> - IMPORT FULL DATABASE
> - INHERIT ANY PRIVILEGES
> - LOGMINING
> - MANAGE ANY FILE GROUP
> - MANAGE ANY QUEUE
> - MANAGE FILE GROUP
> - USE ANY JOB RESOURCE
> - USE ANY SQL TRANSLATION PROFILE